# Cordova not working with visual studio 2015

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, visual-studio-2015

I have a problem with Cordova on Visual Studio 2015. When I use the blank project in javascript and I run to see whether or not it works, it fails with the following message in the output console:

> Clear cache and try building again.

I did this and I installed Cordova again, but nothing changed.

Comment: Could you post the entire contents of the output window somewhere for me to look at?

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error BLD401 Error : BLD00401 : Could not find module 'C:\Users\Eric\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\app.js'. Please Go to Tools --> Options --> Tools for Apache Cordova --> Cordova Tools --> Clear Cordova Cache and try building again. BlankCordovaApp1  1

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me what version of node you have installed? Disclosure: I work on the visual studio tools for Apache Cordova at Microsoft.

Comment: Of course :). I have this version => V0.12.0. it might be node no?

Comment: It was that!!!! the version of Node ^^. tjanks I have another problem with ionic this time, I close the topic now